# Select records that haven't specific value as a child

Tags: mysql, eloquent

[image]

I want to get users filtered by category, so I send category_id as a parameter and should select users who **haven't** records in users_categories_restrictions table with this category_id.

How can I make this eloquent query ??

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Ideally, you would write the MySQL query first, followed by attempting the Eloquent code.

Comment: yes I tried :
User::query()
        ->leftjoin('users_categories_restrictions as ucr','ucr.user_id','=','users.id')
        ->when(isset($request->category_id) , function ($q) use ($request) {
                    
              return $q->whereDoesntHave('ucr.category_id',$request->category_id);
        })
        ->get();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`whereDoesntHave`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

```
$users = App\User::whereDoesntHave('categories', function ($query) use($cat_id) {
    $query->where('categories.id', '=', $cat_id);
})->get();
```

I assume you have defined many to many relation between user and category model

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'users_categories_restrictions', 'user_id');
    }
}


class Category extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'users_categories_restrictions', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: User and UserCategoryRestriction models have 1-M relation , and UserCategoryRestriction and Category models have 1-M relation .. but i didn't defined M-M relation between User and Category models .. should I add it to make it work ?

Comment: your answer returns this error :
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2450:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::categories()

Comment: @RowaydaKhayri I have udpated my answer for M-M mapping between your models